What does 'a tidy step' mean
I'm reading Agatha Christie's novel: The Secret Adversary, and there's a sentense that I could not understand.
The character in the novel asks a porter in station for a way to the house, below is the original sentense:
“Can you tell me the way to the Moat House?”
“The Moat House? It’s a tidy step from here. The big house near the sea, you mean?”

Does the tidy step means 'rather far from here'? Because 'a step from' means nearby or very close, but does the word tidy here means 'a large amount'? So the whole sentense means 'rather far' but not 'very close', or it just literally means very close?

One meaning of tidy is "large or substantial". It's often used in financial settings: A tidy sum of money. So yes, here it means "a large distance".

Yes, tidy in this context means considerable.

3 (adjective)  in the sense of considerable
Definition
quite large (informal)
The opportunities are there to make a tidy profit.

The example roughly means The Moat House is at a considerable distance from here.

The example quoted in A Shropshire word-book, a glossary of archaic and provincial words, &c., used in the county, by Georgina Frederica Jackson (1879) suggests that it could mean "a bit of a walk" even though the definition offered suggests that one could substitute "considerable distance".
it's a tidy step theer an' back; I doubt yo'n be despert tired.  [my emphasis]

TIDY [tei di'], ad. This word has a wide range of meaning beyond the ordinary one of neat; it signifies-commonly-honest, thrifty, honourable of good report;' pleasing, civil; pretty good, above mediocrity; considerable, as in value, size, quantity, distance, and so forth, in the idiomatic sense of good. (1) E's a right tidy mon, is John, al'ays stiddy at 'is work i' the wik, an' reg'lar at Church o' Sund'ys-it's a pity as theer inna more like 'im.' (2) ''Er's sich a tidy spoken ooman.' (3) 'Yo'n got a tidy pig theer, Tummas.' (4) They tellen me as 'e's comen into a tidy property:'-'the Missis gid me a tidy piece o' pork:-we'n a tidy tuthree o' pars this 'ear: it's a tidy step theer an' back; I doubt yo'n be despert tired.'

